# ERROR in ./src/redux/store.js 5:26-34 export 'reducers' (imported as 'reducers') was not found in './reducers/index' (possible exports: default)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently learning redux and i have no idea why my code wouldn't work, especially since i have the same code as the instructor. i get these error messages:

```
ERROR in ./src/redux/store.js 5:26-34

export 'reducers' (imported as 'reducers') was not found in './reducers/index' (possible exports: default)
```

```
Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
    at a (<anonymous>:2587:23)
    at <anonymous>:2593:23
    at <anonymous>:3548:14
    at createStore (redux.js:154:1)
    at Module../src/redux/store.js (store.js:4:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (App.js:11:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

This is my ./reducers/index file:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { productReducers } from "./productReducers";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  allProducts: productReducers,
});

export default reducers;
```

and my redux/store.js:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { reducers } from "./reducers/index";

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

what am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

first install below packages:

1. npm i redux-devtools-extension
2. npm i redux-thunk

then changes in the store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

export default store;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```